# functions, forms, and user entered data

Tags: javascript

I'm a little lost here. What I have is a basic menu with an item and a price, set up as table within a form. I have a text input box for the user to enter a value — the number of that item wanted.

I want to know how I use the data entered into the input text box after the user clicks the calculate button, so that I can validate it and use it in an equation. If the user wants "2" of the item, I need to bring that value into my function so I can validate it as a numeric value. I'll then use it as an integer to multiply it by the price associated with that item...

Here is a sample of my code:

```
        function calculate(){
        var error = false; 
        if (isNaN(*"what would I put here??"*){
            alert("A numeric value is required when ordering steak");
            error = true;
        }
        else{
            var numbercrabcakes = parseInt(-------);
        }
        if (!error)
        {
            total = numbercrabcakes * 15 * 1.0825;
            window.alert("Your order totals: " + total.toFixed(2))
        }
    } 


.........


<form name="myform">
 <script type="text/javascript">
 /* <![CDATA[ */
   document.write("<table border = '1'>")
   document.write("<tr><th>Item Picture</th><th>Item Description</th><th>Item Price</th> \
        <th>Quanity</tr>");
   document.write("<tr><td><img src = 'images/crabcakes.png'></td><td>Cirtus infused crab \                      
   cakes with a sweet and savory sauce</td><td>$" + price[0] + "</td> \
   <td><input type='text' id='crabcakes' size='10' value='0' style='text-align:right;' /></td>
   </tr>");
  /* ]]> */
  </script>
  <p id="submit_button"><input type="submit" value="Calculate" onclick="calculate()" \
       style="width:150px;height:30px;text-align:center;font-weight:bold;" /></p>
</form>
```

The function section of the code was given as a sample/guideline to be used and edited for our specific page. Do I need to give the input box an `id` or `name` and use `getElementbyId` so I can check it against the `isNaN` then use the `parseInt` to convert it as the function shows. I did try that, but it didn't seem to work for me.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question : do you want to know how to call your function on your user input ?

Comment: @fxm i want to know how i call the data entered into the input text box so that i can vaildate it and use it in an equasion. If the user wants "2" of the item. I need to bring that value into my function so i can validate its a numerica value and then use it as an interger to multiply it by the price associated with that item...... does that make sense?

Comment: I think so. If I understand you well, the user writes something in a form, click on submit and your function result should be displayed in a popup ?

Comment: i guess you need to access value of text box which you can do like
$('crabcakes').val()
http://api.jquery.com/val/

Comment: @fxm yes basically, once the user clicks submit, I need to take the data entered and do some calculations and verification. Which will then be displayed in a popup box. In my function how do I "call / associate / use" the data entered in that specific text box. For instance if the user enter "2". I want to take "2" and multiply it by 5.95

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to access the value of your textbox with the id "crabcakes" you could do it like so:

```
function calculate(){
        var value = document.getElementById("crabcakes").value;
        var error = false; 
        if (isNaN(value)){
            alert("A numeric value is required when ordering steak");
            error = true;
        }
        else{
            var numbercrabcakes = parseInt(value);
        }
        if (!error)
        {
            total = numbercrabcakes * 15 * 1.0825;
            window.alert("Your order totals: " + total.toFixed(2))
        }
    }
```

Comment: thank you, this was what i was trying to figure out. thanks again